# Redirect url is not allowed for a preflight request CORS

Tags: node.js, reactjs, cors

So I am developing a full-stack application and faced a CORS problem. The frontend is build from React and backend is build from Node.I want to send a get request from frontend to backend. And backend will redirect to a URL. I was wondering if that's possible under the CORS policy. I have attempt many different solutions but none works.

Below is my error snippet and my code

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at '...' (redirected from 'http://localhost:9000/auth') from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: Redirect is not allowed for a preflight request.
```

```
router.get("/", async (req, res) => {

  return res.redirect(redirectUrl);
});
```

I also try to set the CORS policy

```
const corsOptions = {
  origin: "*",
  method: "GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS",
  credentials: true,
  optionSuccessStatus: 200,
};

app.use(cors(corsOptions));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use cors package to ignore the localhost exception.

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');

const app = express();
app.use(cors());

require('./route')(app);
```

Comment: How will that ignore the exception? As you can see I did use cors above and error still appears. Also what happen in production since this can only hide localhost exception? Thanks

Comment: Did you try without passing any option?